# Is there a way to identify unused script files in SFCC?

Tags: salesforce-commerce-cloud

We have project that started still on Pipelines and has gone through a lot of phases from using ds pipelets to partial migrations to controllers and require calls over imports.

We are sure, that a lot of dead code is in our repository but have no good way of identifying it.

Anybody knows about a tool or other way to figure this out?

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I extended my existing analyse library: https://github.com/Andreas-Schoenefeldt/SFCCAnalyser

You can clone the repository, and run:

```
npm i
npm start
```

follow the script afterwards and select **detect unused code**

[image]